# Rstudio pandoc issue

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc

This example will knit on my laptop but not my desktop. Both are using the same RStudio and R versions. I have tried uninstalling R and RStudio, changing R and RStudio versions, changing 32/64 bit R, trying to install a variety of pandoc versions, setting the path to pandoc manually with Sys.setenv()... I am sort of at a loss here.

Both machines have the following:

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘1.19.2.1’
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

Here is a minimum non/working example. Again, it works on the laptop but not the desktop.

````
---
title: "Pandoc testing sandbox"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: no
      smooth_scroll: no
---

Here is a chunk of code to test:


```{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}

tex2markdown <- function(texstring) {
  writeLines(text = texstring,
             con = myfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".tex"))
  texfile <- knitr::pandoc(input = myfile, format = "html")
  cat(readLines(texfile), sep = "\n")
  unlink(c(myfile, texfile))
}

textable <- "
\\begin{table}[]
\\centering
\\begin{tabular}{l | c | c}
              & without replacement & with replacement \\\\ \\hline
order matters &  permutation: $\\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & $n^k$  \\\\ \\hline
order does not matter & combination: ${n\\choose k}=\\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ & (\\textit{special case}) \\hline
\\end{tabular}
\\end{table}
"

tex2markdown(textable)
```
````

The error text on the desktop machine is:

```
Line 17 Error in knitr::pandoc(input = myfile, format = "html") : 
Please install pandoc first: http://pandoc.org 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> 
tex2markdown -> <Anonymous> Execution halted
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

===

Edit: I did a bit more testing and ran: 
`rmarkdown::render("pandoctest.Rmd", "html_document")`

And there was an option to "Rerun with Debug", so I did that, and the error is happening in "Function pandoc (namespace:knitr)" The line of code where the break happens in what I suppose is the pandoc function in the knitr package is:

```
...
if (Sys.which("pandoc") == "") 
    stop("Please install pandoc first: http://pandoc.org")
...
```

So it seems like pandoc is checking to see if it is installed itself? Or somehoe this is a pandoc function in the knitr package that is calling an actual pandoc program from somewhere else? SO it seems I need to get knitr to somehow see that I have pandoc installed.